# Access unserialized object with Jquery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I used this code to unserialize my form-data:

```
$data = $this->Js->get('#Form')->serializeForm(array('isForm' => true, 'inline' => true)

$.unserialize('.$data.') // I work with CakePhp so I can use variables ;)
```

Well, let's assume this code is correct ;)

When I console.log the last code-rule i get:

```
Object {_method: "POST", data[Rating][itemtype]: "Upload", data[Rating][itemid]: "73", data[Rating][rate]: "4"}
```

This looks very good to me: i need to get the `data[Rating][itemid]`!

But.... How? I can't figure it out!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I am one step closer... I found out I can do:

```
$.unserialize('.$data.')._method // Output: POST
```

But, my next problem: When i do:

```
$.unserialize('.$data.').data[Rating][itemtype] // Mark up the '[' and ']'
```

I get the next error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: Rating is not defined